# Javascript multi-value array

Tags: java, javascript

This may seem like a rather odd/dumb question but I would like to replicate the following JavaScript array in Java.

```
var myArray = new Array();          
myArray[0] = ['Time', 'Temperature'];
myArray[1] = ['00:02', 20];
myArray[2] = ['01:30', 21];
```

What is strange to me is that there are multiple values in a single array location so I don't know what is going on; is this a two-dimensional array?

Comment: It's an array of arrays.  That's *kind-of* like a two-dimensional array, but it's not stored the way a 2D array would be stored in C or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java:

```
Object[][] myArray = {
    new Object[]{"Time", "Temperature"},
    new Object[]{"00:02", 20},
    new Object[]{"01:30", 21}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this manner:

```
String[][] myArray = {
    {"Time", "Temperature"},
    {"00:02", "20"},
    {"01:30", "21"}
};
```

Although I don't recommend this since you're losing a lot of type information and using `String` for everything doesn't scale well and isn't very maintainable. It is probably better to create a `TemperatureReading` class and have a list of `TemperatureReading` instances.